# Yii input field enable / disable with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have 2 input field, but database label 1 like below:

[image]

I need if I select from dropdown then value save from dropdown or write on input field without dropdown then save from input field, currently required both I need `any one`

Below code:

```
<?php 

    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'name', 
    CHtml::listData(menu::model()->findAll('view_status=:view_status',
    array('view_status'=>"Enabled"),
    array('order'=>'label DESC')), 'label', 'label'), 
    array('empty' => 'Select','class'=>'form-control')); 

    ?>
  ----
   <?php 
        echo $form->textFieldRow(
        $model,
        'name',
        array('class'=>'form-control')
        );
    ?>
```

How can I reach this solution?

Comment: "*..I need if I select from dropdown then value save from dropdown or write on input field without dropdown then save from input field, currently required both I need any one*" I Didn't get any thing from it. Please explain briefly.

Comment: There are 2 condition `1. dropdown` & `2. write` on same database field, I need `any one`. if i `write ` then save from write. & if I ` select from dropdown` then save from dropdown.

Comment: Now individually work properly

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the text input, then just add a condition in your save method, if the dropdown selected value is different from empty, then take the value from your text input and put it in your original variable.